# How to Switch to Military Time Format and reverse (h12 to h23) (h23 to h12) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have been working on a little clock app that displays standard time on load and has a toggle button that can change the display to military time. However, I would like to use the toggle switch to be able to go back and forth between standard and military time.

As you see, every time I click on the button, it just not to switch to military time also go back and forth between standard and military time continuously.

Any idea to solve it?

```
const headClock = document.createElement("h2");
const dateDay = document.createElement("h2");
const time = document.createElement("h1");
const changeTimeFormat = document.createElement("button");
const div = document.createElement("div");

div.style.cssText = "text-align: center";
headClock.innerHTML = "A Simple Digital Clock";

const weekday = [
  "Sunday",
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday",
  "Saturday",
];
const month = [
  "January",
  "February",
  "March",
  "April",
  "May",
  "June",
  "July",
  "August",
  "September",
  "October",
  "November",
  "December",
];


var isOppen = false;
let myInterval12 = setInterval(timeFor12, 1000);

function timeFor12() {
  isOppen = true;
  time.innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleString("ru-RU", {
    hour12: true,
    timeZone: "Asia/Riyadh",
    // hourCycle: `${hourCycle}`,
    hour: "2-digit",
    minute: "2-digit",
    second: "2-digit",
  });
}

function timeFor24() {
  isOppen = false;
  time.innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleString("ru-RU", {
    hour12: false,
    timeZone: "Asia/Riyadh",
    // hourCycle: `${hourCycle}`,
    hour: "2-digit",
    minute: "2-digit",
    second: "2-digit",
  });
}

const today = new Date();
dateDay.innerHTML = `${weekday[today.getDay()]}, ${
  month[today.getMonth()]
} ${today.getDay()}th ${today.getFullYear()}`;

changeTimeFormat.onclick = () => {
  console.log(isOppen)
  if (isOppen === true) {
    let myInterval24 = setInterval(timeFor24, 1000);
    clearInterval(myInterval24);
    setInterval(timeFor12, 1000);
    isOppen = false;
  } else if (isOppen === false){
    clearInterval(myInterval12);
    setInterval(timeFor24, 1000);
    isOppen = true;
  }
  // isOppen ? timeFor24() : timeFor12();
};

changeTimeFormat.innerHTML = `Switch to Military Time Format`;

div.appendChild(headClock);
div.appendChild(time);
div.appendChild(dateDay);
div.appendChild(changeTimeFormat);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: `clearInterval()` requires that you *save* the returned value from `setInterval()` and pass that in to clear the timer.

Answer (score 2):

You can greatly simplify your code as follows:

```js
        const headClock = document.createElement("h2");
        const dateDay = document.createElement("h2");
        const time = document.createElement("h1");
        const changeTimeFormat = document.createElement("button");
        const div = document.createElement("div");

        div.style.cssText = "text-align: center";
        headClock.innerHTML = "A Simple Digital Clock";

        const weekday = [
          "Sunday",
          "Monday",
          "Tuesday",
          "Wednesday",
          "Thursday",
          "Friday",
          "Saturday",
        ];
        const month = [
          "January",
          "February",
          "March",
          "April",
          "May",
          "June",
          "July",
          "August",
          "September",
          "October",
          "November",
          "December",
        ];


        let is24 = true;
        setInterval(updateTime, 1000)

        function updateTime() {
        
          const now = new Date();
          dateDay.innerHTML = `${weekday[now.getDay()]}, ${
            month[now.getMonth()]
          } ${now.getDay()}th ${now.getFullYear()}`;

        
          time.innerHTML = now.toLocaleString("ru-RU", {
            hour12: !is24,
            timeZone: "Asia/Riyadh",
            hour: "2-digit",
            minute: "2-digit",
            second: "2-digit",
          });
        }
        
        changeTimeFormat.onclick = () => {
          is24 = !is24;
          changeTimeFormat.innerHTML = `Switch to ${is24?'Regular':'Military'} Time Format`;
          updateTime();
        };

        changeTimeFormat.onclick();

        div.appendChild(headClock);
        div.appendChild(time);
        div.appendChild(dateDay);
        div.appendChild(changeTimeFormat);
        document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Note that you need to ensure you update the date string too, so it will be correct when the day of the year changes.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet is a simplification of your code. It uses [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to handle the button click. The clock 'runs' using `setTimeout` in a recursive function. To retrieve a date string with 12/24-hour time it uses the `hc` extension of the locale. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) for more information on that.

The 'state' of the time string is saved in a [data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) of the time element.

All steps in the snippet contain comment to (hopefully) make things a bit more clear.

If you want to use more formatting for the datetime, maybe my small [formatting module](https://github.com/KooiInc/dateformat) is useful.

```js
// use event delegation to handle button click
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

// create the elements
createDocument();

// timer: for saving the currently running setTimeout
// and being able to stop it (on button click)
let timer = null;

// run the clock
runClock();

// ----------------------------------------------------- //
//                      functions                        //
// ----------------------------------------------------- //

// get a time string from a given date
// use hc locale extension (-u-hc-) for military or 12 hour clock
// h24 === true returns 'military time'. Note that it will return
// 24:00, 24:01 etc. for times after midnight. Use 'h23' if 
// midnight should be 00:00
function getTimeString(d = new Date, h24) {
  return d.toLocaleString(`ru-RU-u-hc-${h24 ? `h24` : `h12`}`, {
    timeZone: "Asia/Riyadh", hour: "2-digit",
    minute: "2-digit", second: "2-digit", } ); 
};

// fill in a localized string for the date
function fillDateString(d) {
  const format = { 
    day: `numeric`,  month: `long`, 
    weekday: `long`, year: `numeric` };
  document.querySelector(`#dateStr`).innerHTML = 
    d.toLocaleString(`ru-RU`,  format)
      .concat(`<br>(${d.toLocaleString(`en-us`, format)})`);
}

// 'run' the clock and rerun it every second (1000ms).
function runClock() {
  const timeElement = document.querySelector(`#timeStr`);
  
  // refresh date
  const dtNow = new Date();
  
  // fill in the refreshed time (using the saved 24/12-hour setting)
  timeElement.textContent = 
    getTimeString(dtNow, timeElement.dataset.ish24 === `true`);
  
  // fill in the refreshed date
  fillDateString(dtNow);
  
  // restart the clock
  timer = setTimeout(runClock, 1000);
}

function handle(evt) {
  // only do something if the click originated from the button
  // identified by the id
  if (evt.target.id === `h24Switcher`) {
    
    // retrieve the timeElement
    const timeElement = document.querySelector(`#timeStr`);
    
    // stop the timeout
    clearTimeout(timer);
    
    // determine 24/12-hour state and save the opposite state
    // to the data attribute
    timeElement.dataset.ish24 = !(timeElement.dataset.ish24 === `true`);
    
    // change button text according to the current 21/12-hour state
    evt.target.textContent = timeElement.dataset.ish24 !== `true` 
      ? `Military format` : `12 Hour format`;
    
    // restart the clock (it will automatically fill in the correct
    // time string based on the saved 24/12-hour state and the 
    // localized date and english date)
    return runClock();
  }
}

// create elements and return the time element for later use
function createDocument() {
  // create the root div element
  const div = document.body.insertAdjacentElement(`beforeend`, 
    document.createElement("div") );
  
  // create and append a header
  div.insertAdjacentElement(`beforeend`, 
    Object.assign( document.createElement("h2"), 
      {className: `center`, innerHTML: `A Simple Digital Clock`} ) );
  
  // create and append an element for the time
  div.insertAdjacentElement(`beforeend`, 
    Object.assign( document.createElement("h1"), 
      {id: `timeStr`, className: `center`} ) );
    
  // create and append an element for the date
  div.insertAdjacentElement(`beforeend`, 
    Object.assign( document.createElement("h2"), 
      {id: `dateStr`, className: `center bold`} ) );
    
  // create and append a (centered) button
  div.insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, `
    <div class="center bttnBox">
      <button id="h24Switcher">Military format</button>
    </div>`);
}
```

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

h1, h2 {
  margin-bottom: -0.5rem;
}

.bttnBox {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: It Works perfectly!
Thanks A lot for both of you.
I hope you get well soon Kooilnc.

Comment: Mr Kooilnc, 
As beginner, I can't understand some of your code.

Comment: Hi @Salman, I have modified the answer and added a lot of (hopefully clarifying) comment

Comment: Thanks A lot Mr Kooilnc.
You are the best.